# Python Multithreading no current event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, web-scraping, python-multithreading

My Threading works fine only when fetch() is not called from validate(). But in this scenario below it returns

**RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread**

in all the threads 0 - 99 what am I doing wrong here ?

```
from threading import Thread
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def fetch():
    #fetch data from another site
    session = HTMLSession()
    url='http://url'
    data = session.get(url)
    data.html.render()
    content = data.html.html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    iban = soup.find('p',{"id":"demo"})
    return result.text

def validate():    
    url = "https://url"
    payload = {
        "data" : fetch(),
        "veto" : "fi"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    data = soup.body.find(text='contact')
    if(data):
        print (data)
    else:
        print ("no data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = []
    for i in range(100):
        # We start one thread per url present.
        process = Thread(target=validate)
        process.start()
        threads.append(process)
```

Comment: Most people use scrapy for things like this and for good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick search of the error, I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2308) that seems to show your problem and its solution.

It looks like you need to use `asyncio` and, at the beginning of each running thread, call `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())`.

Comment: you mean define it inside validate() or fetch()  ? 
edit: i tried in both didnt work :(

Comment: from the different things I've seen online, it looks like you just add `import asyncio` to your imports and `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())` to the beginning of `validate`. I'm investigating but I'm not too familiar with the subject

Comment: I just recreated the problem on my computer and through trial-and-error determined that the error is caused by `data.html.render()`. Every thread gave that "There is no current event loop in thread" error. As soon as I added that `asyncio.set_event_loop...` line to the beginning of `validate` (and, of course, called `import asyncio` at the top of the file) that error disappeared. There are still more errors, but they seem to be from the fact that I'm not getting/posting with the URLs you plan to use.